# How do you make a button do something different after a certain number of times of clicking it?

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a text adventure and I haven't done Javascript in a while, and I want the "Feel around the cave" button in my code to go to "d" the second time clicking it.  How do I do this? Here's my current code:

```
<script>
function one()
{
    var newButton1 = '<button id="btnTwo" onclick="two()" >Pick up stick</button>';
    var newButton2 = '<button id="btnThree" onclick="three()">Leave it there</button>';
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="You feel something on the ground, and you think it's a stick."+newButton1+newButton2;
}

function two()
{
   document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="You pick up the stick. It might be useful for something."; 

   document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';

}

function three()
{
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="You leave the stick on the ground and continue on.";

    document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';
}

function four()
{
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML="You find another stick stuck to the wall with something that feels like honey. You can also feel some rocks stuck to the wall next to it.";
}
</script>

<div style="margin-left:15px; width:200px; margin-top:100px;">
    <button onclick="one()">Feel around the cave</button>
</div>

<div id="entire" style="margin-left:490px; margin-top:-22px; width:400px; height:600px;>
   <div id="d"></div>
   <div id="c"></div>
   <div id="b"></div>
   <div id="a"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you not use a counter or something, then do an `if` test on it to see how many times you clicked the button and do something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldnt mess with onclick="" but since you did it like this, do

Assign id to the button, lets say id="btn_feelAround" then in the end of one() function do

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('btn_feelAround');
myButton.onclick = four;
```

I did it here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YL5rC/4/)

Also, try to learn jquery or something like this, it might make a lot things easier for you